# VB: Formatting Mysql Timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I don't know how to format a timestamp in VB so it gets inserted into the MYSQL database in this format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00
```

I tried:

```
Dim timestamp As Date = TimeValue(Now)
```

It formats it as `0001-01-01 12:33:38` -- This would be correct if the `yyyy-mm-dd` was actually the correct date.

Comment: It might easier to setup your MySQL queries to accept whatever VB is providing as strings, and convert the value to a MySQL DATETIME using [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: I also did a timestamp.ToString so it can be a string and after I did that is when I got the output in the question. I would I write what you suggested?

Comment: In VBA - `Format(Now,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed the point.

Real timestamps in sql databases are *never* formatted `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00`.  That's just how they are displayed in a query or data window.  These values are actually *stored* in a binary format that is often not human readable, though mysql might still use unix time.

The point is that you don't even need to know for certain what the actual format is.  This should be handled by your database connection provider, rather than formatting it yourself.  Inserting/updating  a database timestamp correctly for mysql from VB.Net should look something like this:

```
Dim sql As String = "UPDATE `Table` Set MyColumn= @DateValue WHERE ID= @ID"
Using cn As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string here"), _
      cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateValue", MySqlDbType.Datetime).Value = Now
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 12345

    cn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

No formatting necessary.  You could also just write the query this way:

```
Dim sql As String = "UPDATE `Table` Set MyColumn= current_timestamp WHERE ID= @ID"
```

But if you *really* insist on creating the string, it would look like this:

```
Now().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

using the format string instructions available here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx